# How do I get a python bot to read unicode without crashing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, unicode, git-bash

I am currently working with a bot that runs on picarto using gitbash, anytime someone uses emojis on the chat the bot gives me the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 107, in start
    await task
  File "E:\-\Client.py", line 76, in main
    await self.listen()
  File "E:\-\Client.py", line 173, in listen
    await self.print_override(printable)
  File "E:\-\Client.py", line 436, in print_override
    print(text)
  File "C:\Users\-\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f914' in position 49: character maps to <undefined>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 181, in main
    _loop.run_until_complete(start())
  File "C:\-\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "Main.py", line 110, in start
    print(sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\-\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f914' in position 111: character maps to <undefined>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 194, in main
    print(sys.exc_info(encoding='utf-8'))
  File "C:\-\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f914' in position 173: character maps to <undefined>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Main.py", line 202, in <module>
        main()
      File "Main.py", line 198, in main
        print(sys.exc_info())
      File "C:\-\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
        return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f914' in position 244: character maps to <undefined>
```

So far I have tried:

> Setting Gitbash to read utf-8
>   downloading something from pip and recalling it in usercustom.py I tried to make to fix the issue with the following code (I might have done this wrong)

```
import win_unicode_console

win_unicode_console.enable()
```

I tried manually shoving encoding= 'utf-8' into script but it causes it to crash as well

I'm kinda stumped on what I need to do to fix this issue

Any form of suggestion I could take to fix this?

Currently using python 3.8

--EDIT--

Here is a snippet from one of the scripts that gives me errors 'cp1253.py'
The one it keeps dinging for the charmap error is line 19

```
9 class Codec(codecs.Codec):
10
11    def encode(self,input,errors='strict'):
12        return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
13
14    def decode(self,input,errors='strict'):
15        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
16
17class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
18    def encode(self, input, final=False):
>>>19        return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
20
21class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
22    def decode(self, input, final=False):
23        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
24
25class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):
26    pass
27
28class StreamReader(Codec,codecs.StreamReader):
29    pass
```

Comment: Are you using `print()` statements? Have you tried writing to a file instead?

Comment: Note: when you have an encode error, the problem is writing, not reading.

Comment: @Nraco Can you share your code snippet?

Comment: Where should I snip from? The main.py or the client.py or one of the other plugins?... 
The two text I linked are: The gitbash logs and the entire usercustomize.py file @Rohan Bojja

Comment: The cp1252.py, that's where the crash is happening. I'm not entirely familiar with what you're trying to achieve, but I guess I can help if you share that file.

Comment: @Nraco and also wherever `codecs.charmap_encode()` is defined.

Comment: @Rohan Bojja 
I added in the text that gives the error. I should add that this specific code seems to be manually adding in individual special letters, the majority of the ones listed are all the special latin letters
Example:
#  0xE3 -> LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH TILDE

Comment: @Nraco Did you trying commenting it out?

Comment: You need to post code from `Main.py` and `Client.py` if you want more help. It should be easy to fix. Somewhere in your code, a `str` is being encoded to `bytes` with the `cp1253` charset, instead of the `utf-8` charset.